# How to change gulp port according to specific path

Tags: java, angularjs, gruntjs, gulp

I'm new with gulp i'm using gelp server for my application and i have a java server lanched on port 8080 i want to use oAuth2 for authentication in another project i used grunt an this how i redirected user to oAuth2

here my gruntfile code

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  }, proxies: [
    {
      context: [
        '/_ah',
        '/secured',
        '/oauth2login',
        '/oauth2callback'
      ],
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      https: false,
      changeOrigin: false,
      xforward: false
    }
  ]
}
```

now i want to do same thing on gulp here my gulpfile.js code

```
var options = {
    port: 3000,
    ghostMode: {
        clicks: false,
        location: false,
        forms: false,
        scroll: true
    },
    injectChanges: true,
    logFileChanges: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    logPrefix: 'gulp-patterns',
    notify: true,
    reloadDelay: 0, //1000,
    online: false,
    proxies: [
    {
      context: [
        '/_ah',
        '/secured',
        '/oauth2login',
        '/oauth2callback'
      ],
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      https: false,
      changeOrigin: false,
      xforward: false
    }
  ]
};
```

i added proxies but didn't work i want to do this because in my app.run i want authentify user using oAuth2

here my app.run

```
app.run(function($rootScope, datastoreUser){

  datastoreUser.LoginUser("me").then(function(result){

    console.log("User is authenticated");
    console.log(result);

  },function(error){
    console.log("An error occured user is not authenticated");
    console.log(error);
    window.location.href = '/oauth2login';
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question if anyone else need it

i added http-proxy-middleware module here the code

```
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');
var options = {
    port: 3000,
    ghostMode: {
        clicks: false,
        location: false,
        forms: false,
        scroll: true
    },
    injectChanges: true,
    logFileChanges: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    logPrefix: 'gulp-patterns',
    notify: true,
    reloadDelay: 0, //1000,
    online: false
};
function serveApp() {
    gulp.watch([config.sass], ['sass']);

    options.server = {
        baseDir: [
            config.client,
            config.tmp
        ]
    };
    options.files = [
        config.client + '/**/*.*',
        '!' + config.sass,
        config.tmp + '/**/*.css'
    ];

    options.middleware = proxyMiddleware([
        '/_ah',
        '/secured',
        '/oauth2login',
        '/oauth2callback'
      ],
    {
      target: 'http://localhost:8080'
    });

    browserSync(options);
}
```